# Visual Studio twice as slow

Tags: c++, performance, visual-studio-2019

After running my code again after two weeks time, my code suddenly runs more than twice as slow.
On GitLab I reverted to earlier commits and where those projects used to run at 3500ms the same process now takes over 8000ms.

Updating Visual Studio 2019 to version 16.11.5 did not solve the problem, nor did repairing Visual Studio, cleaning up my computer, updating Windows, or restarting. The problem exists both in Debug mode and Release mode.

Did anyone ever experience similar problems with Visual Studio and found the cause?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what runs at 3500ms and what runs at 8000ms. The same source code but with two versions of VS? Two different versions of the source code, but the same version of VS? Can you find the exact commit that takes you from 3500ms to 8000ms and take a look at what that commit changed?

Comment: I have found similar problems, but as is almost always the case, they were caused by either me (sometimes measuring a debug build) or a colleague, not by the tools. You need to figure out exactly what changed between then and now – code doesn't slow down by magic.

Comment: Also AV can cause this. Every second monday of month at work is a slow monday because of enterprise KAV. You will not see cpu sage if you dont have enterprise admin privileges, it hides its file system usage as well, but compilation is 3-4 times slower and everything is slow while KAV does its scan.

Comment: Another common cause: You could have some background process, such as a windows update, running in the background hogging your system's resources in a way that's not user-interfering, but affects compute-heavy operations.

Comment: Maybe your CPU is overheating, causing it to throttle down, making your whole PC slower?

Comment: Maybe indexer is still crawling whole project, making slowness.

Comment: My project is a ray tracer, and the 3500ms/8000ms is the time it takes to render a single frame in Debug mode. The weird thing is that even if I revert to previous commits, it still runs slower than what I measured on those commits two weeks ago. Updating VS made no difference. The problem persists today, no background apps running, no new programs installed. I did just notice that, when I used to run my app, my laptop's cooling system would be roaring while its quiet now. Could this indicate that my CPU performance is decreased, and how should I fix this? Changing the power plan did not help

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik How should I fix that?

Comment: Does project’s cache or maybe some drive applications affect the speed?